# How to create a webview with only code

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

We are trying to create a simple app in xcode 5 targeting ios 7. We want to create a simple webview but we do not care to use the storyboard to set the whole thing up.

Is it possible to create a webview (and set the proportions/position) by only using a code snippet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a [`UIWebView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/) instance and add it to a container view. You can defined the container view in code, a nib, or a storyboard.

`CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100); // Give the frame a position and size
   UIWebView *webView = [UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
   [containerView addSubView:webView];
   [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL urlWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];`